# Application Insights doesn't work if you have Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus Nuget package installed

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-application-insights, azureservicebus

We have an e-commerce ASP .NET MVC application which posts a message in an Azure Service Bus Queue at some point. To interact with the Azure Service Bus we are using **Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus v5.0** package.

Application is hosted in Azure as a WebApp so we are using **Application Insights** to monitor it but because of the fact that **Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus** starting with the version 3.0 has a dependency on **System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource** monitoring is failing (basically nothing is logged to Application Insights).

We found out that this is an known issue:
[Troubleshooting Application Insights Agent (formerly named Status Monitor v2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/status-monitor-v2-troubleshoot)

The question is there are other solutions than downgrade **Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus** package to version 2?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the response below help?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question correctly, it asks about how to handle this situation where the two nugets have conflicting version requirements for a common child (`System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource`) nuget.

In such cases, you should always use a version of one of the former nugets which has the version of the child nuget version lower as compared to the other. For example, in this case you should use below two compatible nuget packages:

[image]

[image]